# Does Silverlight5 provide anything new for WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight

From WCF standpoint, just wondering whether I can leverage anything after upgrade from `Silverlight 4` to `Silverlight 5`? I did some research regarding new features of `SL5` and cannot find anything about changes to `System.ServiceModel` and `System.ServiceModel.Web` namespaces, is it rigth that nothing were added or am I missing something?

**My Questions:**

- Have there been any changes to WCF in Silverlight 5?
- If yes, has there been any changes to duplex polling on HTTP?

Comment: Amazing! I've posted this question here since was thinking (and still do) that this is Off-topic for StackOverflow but what I see now - question going to be closed because someone think it is offtopic here and should be on Stackoverflow, great! As far as I understand stackoverflow is for concrete technical questions...

Answer (score 2):

Tomasz Janczuk wrote a great series of articles on the HTTP Polling Duplex protocol. Specifically, you might want to look at [this one](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/09/scale-out-of-silverlight-http-polling.html) which discusses scalability directly.

The gist of it is that in order to provide scalability, you have to support the Duplex Service with a backend bus architecture. The services would be responsible just for shuttling messages from the client to the backend. The backend would be responsible for identifying where outgoing messages should be routed and how to process inbound messages.

Comment: I know these articles and this is a great job, they helped me implement this protocol and understand many things, but they are related to `Silverligth 4` time so obviously nothing said about `Silverligth 5` those days

Comment: My apologies...the only new feature in Silverlight 5 related to web calls is the [asynchronous network stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg986857(v=vs.95).aspx) listed under performance improvements.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and what it's good for? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat edit made. Better :)

Comment: @MikeBrown: my question is not about duplex protocol/implementation but about what's new in Silverlight `5`, a lot of internet blog posts saying that there are some neat network performance improvements for HTTP scenarios but no more details, neither on MSDN nor those blog posts.